# Access and use activity nav drawer from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

Is there a way possible to access the navigation drawer I created in my activity from my fragment? I also want to be able to use the back pressed feature. My activity is launched on handsets and my fragment is launched on tablets.

**activity class**

```
public class BakerlooHDNActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Drawer result = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bakerloo_hdn);


        final String actionBarColor = "#B36305";

        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        if(getSupportActionBar()!=null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + getResources().getString(R.string.hdn) + "</font>"));
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + getResources().getString(R.string.zone_3) + "</font>"));

            final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
            upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        }

        // start of navigation drawer
        headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(getActivity())
                .withCompactStyle(true)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.color.bakerloo)
                .withProfileImagesVisible(false)
                .withTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
                .withSelectionListEnabled(false)

                .addProfiles(
                        new ProfileDrawerItem().withName(getString(R.string.hdn)).withEmail(getString(R.string.hello_world))
                )
                .build();

        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(getActivity())
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(false)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.hello_world).withIdentifier(1).withCheckable(false)
                )
                .build();
        // end of navigation drawer
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (result.isDrawerOpen()) {
            result.closeDrawer();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(new Intent("BACKPRESSED_TAG"));
    }
}
```

**fragment class**

```
public class FragmentBakerlooHDN extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public FragmentBakerlooHDN() {
        // Required empty constructor
    }

    BroadcastReceiver onNotice = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             result.closeDrawer();
        }
    };

    private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
    private Drawer result = null;

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("BACKPRESSED_TAG"));

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bakerloo_hdn, container, false);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your fragment is FragmentBakerlooHDN. Where is the call to it? I expect from the Activity.

Comment: Why do you instantiate class AccountHeaderBuilder in both Activity and Fragment? Is that the intentional design?

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid Apologies, that wasn't supposed to be there - it has been removed.

Comment: How is your progress so far? What have you tried? If no response, I will concentrate on helping others.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid After using your code, `headerResult` in `myFragment.setDrawer(headerResult);` becomes underlined in red and I get an error please view my image link for further details as well as the code link below:  [image](http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2015-08-13_at_13.02.32-4up5yJXb.png) • [java code](http://pastebin.com/sa8MSsmZ)

Comment: The issue is just a compile error. You'll have to satisfy the compiler. I added comments in my post. Pls use the same thread instead of this one to avoid confusion since your response is more related to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I would never have a fragment access the drawer directly. Instead I would call the Activity via a callback method from the Fragment and then access the drawer.

After re-reading your question I suggest the following:

- You Activity is already closing the drawer so no need to do it again in the fragment.
- You should have 2 fragments, one for tablet and one for phone

If you still need to communicate with the Fragment do this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (result.isDrawerOpen()) {
        result.closeDrawer();
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG").doSomething();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In your Fragment add this:

```
public void doSomething() {
    // Do it here
}
```

Comment: What needs to go in the fragment code to replace `// Do it here`? My activity and fragment have their own xml layouts (as indicated in the code I posted) `activity_bakerloo_hdn.xml` and `fragment_bakerloo_hdn.xml`.

Comment: Depends what you wantedt to do. Your orginal code said  `// do something when back in activity is pressed`

Comment: I want the nav drawer to close

Comment: You should do that in the Activity.

Comment: I have but my tablet opens a fragment, NOT an activity

Comment: Your activity should control the drawer and fragments. Please read some background info on the roles of Activity and Fragment.

Comment: Unnecessary. I already have a nav drawer in my activity. My phone opens an activity and my tablet opens a fragment from the master detail flow hence it doesn't need to open an activity at all. All I want is the fragment to use the activity's nav drawer when I swipe from the edge of the screen. This can be done but it's a matter of using the right code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is basically to create a public method in the fragment. And the activity calls the public method passing the drawer object. Simple really. This has the effect of passing the drawer by reference.

**Code suggestion.**
In BakerlooHDNActivity class:

```
AccountHeader headerResult;

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   FragmentBakerlooHDN myFragment = new FragmentBakerlooHDN();
   myFragment.setDrawer(headerResult);
}
```

In FragmentBakerlooHDN class:

```
private AccountHeader myDrawer;

public void setDrawer(final AccountHeader drawer) {
   this.myDrawer = drawer;
}
```

Notes:

- You may pass the object headerResult onto FragmentBakerlooHDN constructor but that is normally not done due to fragment lifecycle, I believe.
- For now, you may call the public setDrawer immediately after creating new instance of the fragment. But there may be issues with UI and fragment lifecycle.
- If you modify contents of the drawer, either do it in activity or fragment, not both. Again, this solution is passing the drawer object by reference. So it is powerful enough to be dangerous. Another method would be to use the technique of using callback/listener like what Sweder has said.
- Object myDrawer is declared as AccountHeader instead of AccountHeaderBuilder.

Comment: @MacaronLover, I added comments under EDIT section. Your issue is a simple compile error. It just needs the same class type. I think declaring headerResult as AccountHeader is not right, and it's probably not intentional. You have code of "headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder..." So I think my code suggestion is correct.

Comment: @MacaronLover, The lesson here is that you EITHER change the declaration of headerResult in the Activity OR change the declaration of setDrawer(final AccountHeaderBuilder drawer). You can change the parameter type of drawer and the class object myDrawer.

Comment: Doesn't work after using that code, please check these latest screenshots: [screenshot 1](http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2015-08-13_at_18.09.34-UPhC2xKV.png) and [screenshot 2](http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2015-08-13_at_18.10.09-dR0hzChN.png)

Comment: @MacaronLover, I edited my post to add another Notes bullet saying Object myDrawer is declared as AccountHeader. Perhaps this is an easier fix. My problem here is that I don't know your code well and I don't know what AccountHeaderBuilder class requires. It's better if you fix the compile error yourself and tell us how it's fixed. This will reduce the turnaround time and talks about fixing errors, good for all of us...

Comment: @MacaronLover, I also edited the code in FragmentBakerlooHDN to fit my comments.

Comment: After trying that modification, I get 2 errors, please see link: [image with 2 errors](http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2015-08-13_at_19.51.04-Jwzo1BGM.png)

Comment: @MacaronLover, My code suggestion has nothing to do with that error! Maybe with the code changes, you got confused with the code. Note, keep headerResult declared as AccountHeader, that's from the original code, I believe. Just fix the compile error. LIke I said in my response, you know the code better. Don't be afraid! This is simpler than it looks.

Comment: I edited the suggested code in the Activity to include the headerResult declaration to be clear on this compile issue.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use method onBackPressed in Activity. I updated source code of my tutorial about NavigationDrawer (https://github.com/AlexZhukovich/NavigationDrawerTutorial). I hope it's help you. I used NavigationDrawer from com.android.support:design in this tutorial.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mNavigationView))
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

For me it's work in tablet and phone. (Nexus devices).

I created simple activity with fragment for you. This activity shows 2 fragment, but after click to back, delete second fragment.

```
    public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new DummyFragment(), "TEST").commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container2, new DummyFragment(), "TEST2").commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TEST2") != null && getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TEST2").isVisible()) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TEST2")).commit();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private class DummyFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is already in my activity. The problem is to do with the tablet as it opens a fragment, not an activity.

Comment: Try to add tag during add/replace fragment, for it better way use 
`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fargment, "FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();`

After it you can search fragment and do that you need 

`if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG") != null) { fragment.close(); }`

Comment: Where does this need to go?

Comment: During creating fragment `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fargment, "FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();`

and to onBackPressed() this source code `if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG") != null) { fragment.close(); }`